# Common Lisp package for parsing invalid HTML?

Tags: common-lisp, web-scraping, quicklisp

As a learning exercise, I'm writing a web scraper in Common Lisp.  The (rough) plan is:

1. Use [Quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/) to manage dependencies
2. Use [Drakma](http://weitz.de/drakma/) to load the pages
3. Parse the pages with [xmls](http://common-lisp.net/project/xmls/)

I've just run into a sticking point: the website I'm scraping doesn't always produce valid XHTML.  This means that step 3 (parse the pages with xmls) doesn't work.  And I'm as loath to use regular expressions as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) :-)

So, can anyone recommend a Common Lisp package for parsing invalid XHTML?  I'm imagining something similar to the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for .NET ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "closure-html" project (available in Quicklisp) will recover from bogus HTML and produce something with which you can work. I use closure-html together with CXML to process arbitrary web pages, and it works nicely. http://common-lisp.net/project/closure/closure-html/

Comment: closure-html doesn't seem to work under GNU CLISP - but (without wishing to ignite a holy war) it looks like a move to SBCL will be painless.  I still feel like I'm groping around in the Lisp wilderness, but at least now I can hear voices.  Hopefully they're not just in my head :-)

Answer (score 4):

For next visitors: today we have Plump: https://shinmera.github.io/plump

> Plump is a parser for HTML/XML like documents, focusing on being lenient towards invalid markup. It can handle things like invalid attributes, bad closing tag order, unencoded entities, inexistent tag types, self-closing tags and so on. It parses documents to a class representation and offers a small set of DOM functions to manipulate it. You are free to change it to parse to your own classes though.

and them we have other libs to query the document, like [lquery](https://shinmera.github.io/lquery/) (jquery-like) or [CLSS](https://shinmera.github.io/CLSS/) (simple CSS selectors) by the same author.

We also now have a little tutorial on the Common Lisp Cookbook: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/web-scraping.html

See also Common Lisp wiki: http://www.cliki.net/Web

Comment: and now there's a little tutorial: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/web-scraping.html

Answer (score 1):

Duncan, so far I've been successful using Clozure Common Lisp under both Ubuntu Linux and Windows (7 & XP), so if you're looking for an implementation that will work anywhere you might try this one.